# ConcurrentModificationException while adding items to List<String> in RecyclerView's Adapter

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview, concurrentmodification

I'm implementing pagination in RecyclerView so after every ' n ' items, onScroll() calls abstract loadMore() which is implemented in anonymous class in MainActivity shown below.
loadMore() then invokes my AsyncTaskLoader to load items. LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks are set on MainActivity.
Then in onLoadFinished() I call adapter.addItems(List newItems) but in this method CME is thrown.

This is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity ... implements LM.LC{

    //this gets initiliase in onCreate() - activity = this;
    MainActivity activity;

    //RecyclerView's adapter
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    ...
    someMethod() {
        ...
        adapter.addOnScrollListener(new ScrolListener() {
            ...
            @Override
             loadMore() {
                 ...
                 loaderManager.restartLoader(id,null,activity);
             }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader() {

       return new DataLoader(params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(params) {

        adapter.addItems(List<String> someData);
    }
}
```

This is CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter ... {

    /*this is list in which data is to be added and
    onBindViewHolder() populates view's data from it
    */
    List<String> data;

    ...

    addItems(List<String> someData) {
        //first I tried this
        data.addAll(someData);

        //then even I tried this
        ListIterator<String> it = data.listIterator();

        for(Iterator<String> it1 = someData.listItertor();
              it1.hasNext(); ) {
            it.add(it1.next());
        }

        notifyItem...();


    }

}
```

This is my DataLoader

```
class DataLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {

    ...

    DataLoader(someParams) {
        ...
        //some initialization
        ...
    }

    ...loadInBackground() { ... }
}
```

But both approaches throws CME.

I searched over web but can't find anything helpful.

Comment: what loader are you returning from `onCreateLoader` method?

Comment: @pskink I added Loader class and onCreateLoader(). Lemme know if you want something else !